# How to run a simple OpenCV code in C++ on linux?

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

I wrote a simple OpenCV code using C++ and run it in linux:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cv::Mat image;
    image = cv::imread("sajjad.jpg", 1);
 
    cv::namedWindow("Display Image", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cv::imshow("Display Image", image);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

```
opencv_test.cpp:2:10: fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

how to install OpenCV for c++ in linux?

Comment: you building it in wrong way. How do you do that? This should work: `g++ opencv_test.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags opencv)`

Comment: @MarekR zsh: command not found: pkg-config
cv_test.cpp:3:10: fatal error: 'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1- Install dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config
```

2- To compile OpenCV you will need a C++ compiler. Usually it is G++/GCC or Clang/LLVM. also OpenCV uses CMake build configuration tool:

```
sudo apt install -y g++
sudo apt-get install cmake make
```

3- Clone repository using git:

```
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git
```

4- Create build directory:

```
mkdir -p build && cd build
```

5- Configure - generate build scripts for the preferred build system:

```
cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../opencv_contrib/modules ../opencv
```

6- Build - run actual compilation process. 4 is number of used processor cores. this part may takes some minutes.

```
make -j4
```

7- Installation process copies files to predefined locations and do minor patching:

```
sudo make install
```

7.1- You can remove opencv if you want:

```
sudo make uninstall
```

8- Create a CMake file. the name of the source code is `DisplayImage.cpp` for example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( DisplayImage )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_executable( DisplayImage DisplayImage.cpp )
target_link_libraries( DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

9- Generate the executable. This part is easy, just proceed as with any other project using CMake:

```
cd <DisplayImage_directory>
cmake .
make
```

10- run executable file:

```
./DisplayImage
```

Comment: Why all the downvotes? Why is this a bad answer?

Comment: what global var OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS mean and do I need to configure myself?

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that you have opencv installed. You can do this by:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libopencv-dev
```

Assuming those steps went well and opencv is installed, and assuming your C++ program is named *main.cpp*, you can run the following command to compile and link your C++ program:

```
g++ main.cpp -o output `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4` -std=c++17
```

**NOTE**: You might need to specify the "-std=c++17" flag as I included in the command if you are using a previous version of C++

Finally, you can run your compiled program using

```
./output
```